# Barplot does not show bar colors when there're 1000 bars (R language)

Tags: r, bar-chart

One of my CSV files have more than 1000 rows of records, and I want to create a bar plot and color the bars with "blue" or "red", depending on the value of each chart. So I did the following, but I noticed that when I plot the entire CSV file, I don't see any "blue" or "red" bars; however, when I truncate the first 50 rows and did the same plot, I was able to see colored bars.

```
> cols<-c("blue", "red")[(x>10)+1]
> barplot(x, col=cols, main="FO1_FO2 Variant Allele Frequencies", xlab="SNPs", ylab="VAF(%)", space=c(0.2, 0.8))
```

[image: The bar chart of first 50 rows]
[image: The bar chart of all the 1000+ rows]

Is there a way to color bars when I have 1000+ bars/rows of data? or is there any better plotting for showing the values and differentiate the differences by color on plot?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is drawing the color, but it is also drawing a border which is covering up the color. Try

```
x<-rpois(1000,7)
cols<-c("blue", "red")[(x>10)+1]
barplot(x, col=cols, 
    main="FO1_FO2 Variant Allele Frequencies", 
    xlab="SNPs", ylab="VAF(%)", 
    space=c(0.2, 0.8),
    border=NA)
```

The `border=NA` will disable the drawing of the border.

[image: barplot without borders]

Comment: thanks, but why border color does not cover the bar colors when I have fewer lines of data (50 in my question)?

Comment: @TonyGW Because there is more room to plot a border. You can see the black lines on the `N=50` case. It wants to draw a 1px border, but if your bar width is only 1px wide, you're basically drawing over the fill. But when `N=50` the bars are wider, say 10px so the border doesn't cover anything up.